# how to fix 100vh with mobile address bar visible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How can i fit my app to screen without scrolling
with ignoring the address bar on mobile web.

deploy: https://rockpaperscissors-4d92e.web.app
repo: https://github.com/UmutPalabiyik/RockPaperScissors

Comment: 100vh is a pain when the device has over scroll (ios etc), one way around it is to use `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', \`${window.innerHeight}px\`);` on load then instead of `height: 100vh` use `height:var(--vh, 100vh)` on things, see https://replit.com/@lcherone/iPad-100vh-fix for example to test with

Answer (score 0):

Try using min height

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```